# After inserting data via mongoose-double no document could be found

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-double and some find-query on created data.

Environment:

- MongoDB: 3.6
- mongoose: 4.13
- mongoose-double: 0.0.1

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-double because i actually use mongoose 4.13.x and the new @mongoosejs/double version requires mongoose 5.x

After inserting some data to a MongoDB schema (using embedded document - but i don't think this is the problem) using the mongoose-double dataType the related data could not be found via a simple query.

Embedded Schema looks like:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
const barsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  val: mongoose.Schema.Types.Double
}
```

Surrounding document:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);
const foosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bars: [barsSchema]
}
```

After inserting some data via mongoose with exponential values like: *2.86530674849058e+161*

The Database looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9f86c53db736eec3cdba00"),
    "bars" : [ 
        {
            "val" : 2.86530674849058e+161
        }, 
        {
            "val" : 2.86530674849058e+161
        }, 
        {
            "val" : 3.86530674849058e+161
        }
    ]
}
```

With all "val" to be a double... I inspected the collection via RoboMongo.

But when doing a simple:

```
db.getCollection('foo').find({
    'bars.val': 2.86530674849058e+161
})
```

**Nothing will be found.**

If I **open** the document via **RoboMongo** and click edit -> **save** (without really changing something) the query works and the **document will be found**.

Collection *foo* and the document look the same - and the *var* field is still type of double... I'm confused...

Any ideas on how to get more details about this behavior?

Thanks in advance
Ralf

Comment: Potentially related: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/699 and https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1447 - I would suggest you try to use `mongo.exe` or another client and have a look at your data.

Comment: Thanks for that hint - i looked at the data with robomongo, mongodb-compass and mongo.sh itself... all look the same. Before and after just open and save with robomongo... but the query only works after touching with robomonog.

Answer (score 0):

As dnickless pointed... robomongo did some small "adjustment" on my data... and searching with the data displayed from robomongo did not run successfull until saving this "wrong" displayed data to mongodb.

- My Application saved: 2.865306748490577e+161
- RoboMongo displayed: 2.86530674849058e+161
- so i searched with 2.86530674849058e+161 and found nothing
- save that "corrupt displayed" document via RoboMongo
- and now you will find something with the "false" data 2.86530674849058e+161

I turned on some query logging on mongodb via

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

to check what was saved and how the query looked like. That gave me the final hint.

Solved for me - thanks!